# How to disable gsm connection

Tags: android, gsm, cellular-network, cellid

I am writing an application for Android, and at this stage, I need help of an experienced programmer (I am only a beginner). Wrote a program to display the currently used base station (CellID and LAC), and display a list of neighboring base stations.
Now came the next question - how to disable the phone to receive the signal from a particular
base station, ie for example, is it possible to disable gsm connection for a given CellID? Are there any for this class and method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not android programmer, but 100% sure you can not selectively control your GSM radio to use/disable particular BTS.

GSM radio has own firmware which do not expose functions like that.

You can list available BTS in range and make selection based on operator ID aka [MCC-MNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code),

then GSM radio will bind primary to BTS of selected operator, or it will use roaming BTS (local or international).